# kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: unable to reach any KDC in realm LOCAL

Tags: domain, kerberos

How I am supposed to configure Kerberos on OS X 10.8 ? I heard that this should work by default, just by calling `kinit` once.

Still, I am on the corporate network (not joined any domain) and run `kinit`.

All, I got was kinit: `krb5_get_init_creds: unable to reach any KDC in realm LOCAL`

Note: I do want to make it work without having to join the Windows domain.

`/var/log/opendirectory.log` shows:

```
2012-09-05 14:05:16.600904 BST - 81.144675 - Client: mds, UID: 0, EUID: 0, GID: 0, EGID: 0
2012-09-05 14:05:16.600904 BST - 81.144675, Module: SystemCache - Misconfiguration detected - Failed to insert key 'ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000037' for entry '0x7fbf0fa01140' into hash 'UUID' as 'non-authoritative'
```

Comment: Did you manage to get to the bottom of this? I am completely new to Kerberos and I'm followith the firefox guide (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/sso-config-firefox.html) for installation on el_capitan

Answer (score 10):

On macOS the default client does not fall back to TCP.

In your `krb.conf` prefix your `kdc` value with `tcp/` to force the client to use TCP if your corporate network blocks UDP (A lot of them do).

```
kdc = tcp/realm.example.com:88
```