# Error when creating Kerberos ticket: "unable to reach any KDC"

Tags: command-line, unix, kerberos

Do you know why I have this message when I use `kinit`?

```
kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: unable to reach any KDC in realm LOCAL, tried 0 KDCs
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Is https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63122/kinit-krb5-get-init-creds-unable-to-reach-any-kdc-in-realm-local#273064 relevant to your setup? About the error:`kinit` is trying to connect to the LOCAL realm but the KDC can't be found , could it be that that port 636/tcp (for ldaps, or 389/tcp for ldap) on the KDC is not reachable from your Mac? Is the KDC correctly configured in `/etc/krb5.conf`? You can find an example of `/etc/krb5.conf` in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053539/openldap-kerberos-unable-to-reach-any-kdc-in-realm.